# How do I localize (i18n) application names in electron-builder?

Tags: electron, localization, internationalization, electron-builder

I use electron-builder to assemble Mac DMG and Windows NSIS installers. I need to have the display name of the application localized to a couple different languages. Is this something electron-builder supports? I found the option to enable multi-lingual installers in NSIS, and I found some documentation about how to internationalize info.plist files in XCode. But I've found nothing specifically about how to provide different names to have under the application once it is installed when using electron-builder.

Is this a supported feature? Any pointers to how-to's would be greatly appreciated.